# Array of GCHandles

Tags: c++-cli

I have an array of byte arrays in c++/cli:

```
array<array<System::Byte>^>^ data;
```

I need to convert it to c++ style vector of pointers

```
vector<uint8_t*> cData;
```

I will then send cData to a function, and release the pinned memory when done.

The code looks like this:

```
void ProcessImages(const std::vector<const uint8_t*> srcImages);

void MyCLIFunc(array<array<System::Byte>^>^ data)
{
     vector<uint8_t*> cData;

     //Does not compile
     std::vector<pin_ptr<Byte>> pinnedVector; // error C3239: 'cli::pin_ptr<unsigned char> *': pointer to interior/pin pointer is disallowed by the common language runtime`

     //Does not compile
     std::vector<GCHandle> gchandles; //>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\vector(935): error C3699: '&&': cannot use this indirection on type '_Ty' with   [ _Ty=System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle  ]

     //Here I want to call ProcessImages, converting data to srcImages without copying mem
     ProcessImages(cData);
}
```

What am I missing, how can I store a collection of GCHandles/pin_ptr?

Thank!!!

Comment: That's not C#, it's in C++ notation.  An array of byte arrays in C# looks like `byte[][]`

Comment: @Flydog57 you are right, I've modified the wording and tags

Comment: It is not a sensible question, there isn't any way to emulate an std::vector by pinning.  it requires a conversion, trivially done with pin_ptr<> so you can use std::begin/end() to call the constructor.  Show your code.

Comment: @HansPassant Added some sample code,  hope my intention is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested:
The problem I ran to is actually pinning of jagged arrays.

I needed to use CLI array to store the handles,
The following code worked for me:

```
auto handles = gcnew cli::array<GCHandle>(dataSize);
for (UInt32 i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle::Alloc(frame[i], GCHandleType::Pinned);
        handles[i] = handle;
        cData.push_back((const uint8_t*)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer());
    }
ProcessImages(cData);
for (UInt32 i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
    handles[i].Free();
```